# Data table header is not aligning for hidden tables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables, bootstrap-modal

am using bootstrap-3 and hiding some tables while loading.
here is my html code

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="box-header">
                @*<h3 class="box-title">Raise Invoice </h3>*@
                &nbsp;
                &nbsp;

                <div class="btn-group" style="float:right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Export</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        @*<li><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/excel.png" /> Excel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/pdf.png" /> PDF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/csv.png" /> CSV</a></li>*@
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("RaiseInvoiceReport", new { type = "EXCEL" })" id="excelExport"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/excel.png" /> Excel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("RaiseInvoiceReport", new { type="PDF"})"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/pdf.png" /> PDF</a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("RaiseInvoiceReportCsv")"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/csv.png" /> CSV</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="btn-group" style="float:right;padding-right: 1%;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="GenerateInvoice"><img src="~/Content/js/plugins/images/add.png" height="17" width="20" /> Generate Invoice</button>
                </div>
                @*<a href="#" class="t-add-user-link"><i class="t-add-new-user-icon" </i><span>Add new user</span></a>*@
            </div>

        </div>

        @if(Model.message!="")
        { 
        <div id="InputError" class="ErrorDiv" style="color: #D8000C; margin: 8px 0px;padding:5px;background-color: #FFBABA;">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle" style="font-size:17px"><strong> Error!</strong></i>
            <ul>
                <li>@Model.message</li>
                </ul>
</div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div id="InputError" class="ErrorDiv" >

            </div>
        }
               <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="phaseTab">

                    <li class="active"><a href="#tab_1" id="RequirementsTab" data-toggle="tab">Screen / Task</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab_2" id="ChangeRequestTab" data-toggle="tab">Change Request</a></li>

                </ul>

                <div class="panel panel-default">


                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div style="width:100%" class="tab-pane active " id="tab_1">
                                <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-RequirementsInvoice">
                                    <thead style="background-color:#E0EEEE">
                                        <tr>

                                            <th>Screen / Task</th>
                                            <th >Product</th>
                                            <th >Source Control Code</th>
                                            <th >SOW Estimate</th>
                                            <th >Complexity</th>
                                            <th >Sprint</th>
                                            <th>Phase</th>
                                            <th>Overall Estimate</th>
                                            <th >Estimated Hours</th>
                                            <th >Actual Hours</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Created Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Created By</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Updated Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Updated By</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Row Version</th>
                                            <th >Invoice Hours</th>
                                            <th >Amount</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Release Date</th>
                                            <th >Select</th>


                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                            <tr>

                                                <td>RequirementName</td>
                                                <td>ProductName</td>
                                                <td>1235</td>
                                                <td>SowEffort</td>
                                                <td>ComplexityName</td>
                                                <td>SprintName</td>
                                                <td>PhaseName</td>
                                                <td>OverallEstimate</td>
                                                <td>EstimatedHours</td>
                                                <td>ActualHours</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">CreatedDate</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">CreatedBy</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">UpdatedDate</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">UpdatedBy</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">RowVersion</td>
                                                <td>InvoiceHours</td>

                                                <td>Amount</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">ReleaseDate</td>
                                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="flat-red"></td>

                                            </tr>


                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width:100%" class="tab-pane  " id="tab_2">
                                <table style="width:100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-ChangeRequestInvoice">
                                    <thead style="width:100%; background-color:#E0EEEE">
                                        <tr>


                                            <th >Screen / Task</th>

                                            <th >Description</th>
                                            <th>Product</th>
                                            <th>Source Control Code</th>
                                            <th>Estimated Hours</th>
                                            <th>Hours Spent</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Created Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Created By</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Updated Date</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Updated By</th>
                                            <th class="hidden">Row Version</th>
                                     <th>Invoice Hours</th>

                                            <th>Amount</th>
                                            <th>Select</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                            <tr >

                                                <td>ChangeRequestName</td>
                                                <td>Description</td>
                                                <td>ProductName</td>
                                                <td>SourceControlId</td>
                                                <td>EstimatedHours</td>
                                                <td>HoursSpent</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">CreatedDate</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">CreatedBy</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">UpdatedDate</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">UpdatedBy</td>
                                                <td class="hidden">RowVersion</td>
                                               <td>InvoiceHours</td>

                                                <td >Amount</td>
                                                <td><input type="checkbox" class="flat-red"></td>

                                            </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now am initialising datatable like this:

```
var RequirementInvoiceTable=$('#dataTables-RequirementsInvoice').DataTable({


     "scrollX": true,
     "scrollCollapse": true,
     "oLanguage": {

         "sInfoEmpty": '',
         "sEmptyTable": "No Data Available",

     }

    });
 var ChangeRequestInvoiceTable=$('#dataTables-ChangeRequestInvoice').DataTable({

     "scrollX": true,
     "fixedHeader": true,
     "scrollCollapse": true,
        "oLanguage": {

            "sInfoEmpty": '',
            "sEmptyTable": "No Data Available",
        }
    });
```

Datatable hedder is not working when i gave XScroll :true 
It is working for the first table which is visible at page loading and is not woking for the page which is hidden.
see the image
[click below to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYvVU.png)

Comment: With the above code we can't see the issue, so you need to post a minimal working code snippet that reproduce it.

Comment: I have edited the same.. with full working code.. kindly have a look on it.. Use bootstrap 3 for css...

Comment: The screen shot and the code you provided doesn't render the same output, so it is very difficult to understand what you mean. You need to figure a way to make it clear for us what is and what isn't.

Comment: actually, when i give xScroll: true for datatable plugin, The hedder is not aligning properly with the body. table body is responsive. But hedder alone is not aligning properly

Comment: Take a look at [**columns.adjust()**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust())